# Why does the sensu-client not start in docker on Travis?

Tags: systemd, sensu, travis-ci

[This Ansible role](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu/blob/master/meta/main.yml) has been created and [this .travis.yml](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-git/blob/master/.travis.yml) has been used as an example in order to test the role. All services were able to start, except the sensu-client.

**Attempts to solve the issue**

In order to solve [the issue](https://travis-ci.org/030/ansible-sensu/jobs/150505474) a debug step was added to travis. When the build completed the following error was thrown:

```
The command "sudo docker exec "$(cat ${container_id})" ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/roles/role_under_test/tests/test-${SITE}.yml | grep -q 'changed=0.*failed=0' && (echo 'Idempotence test: pass' && exit 0) || (echo 'Idempotence test: fail' && exit 1)

" exited with 1.

0.07s$ sudo docker exec --tty "$(cat ${container_id})" env TERM=xterm sudo systemctl status sensu-client.service -l

● sensu-client.service - LSB: Sensu monitoring framework client

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/sensu-client)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-08-08 00:18:20 UTC; 131ms ago

     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

  Process: 1534 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/sensu-client start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 08 00:18:19 c6354976113c systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Sensu monitoring framework client...

Aug 08 00:18:19 c6354976113c sensu-client[1534]: /etc/init.d/sensu-service: line 71: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory

Aug 08 00:18:19 c6354976113c sensu-client[1534]: Starting sensu-client/etc/init.d/sensu-service: line 79: daemon: command not found

Aug 08 00:18:20 c6354976113c sensu-client[1534]: /etc/init.d/sensu-service: line 88: echo_failure: command not found

Aug 08 00:18:20 c6354976113c systemd[1]: sensu-client.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Aug 08 00:18:20 c6354976113c systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Sensu monitoring framework client.

Aug 08 00:18:20 c6354976113c systemd[1]: Unit sensu-client.service entered failed state.

Aug 08 00:18:20 c6354976113c systemd[1]: sensu-client.service failed.
```

When the ansible role is deployed on a remote system the sensu-client starts, but it fails on Travis although the other services are able to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concise**

The `initscripts` package was missing. This was found after comparing the files that reside in `/etc/init.d` on a local system with the ones that reside in the docker container used by Travis. After querying for `/etc/init.d/functions` it became clear what package had to be installed.

**Verbose**

It seems that files are missing in `/etc/init.d`, i.e.:

```
Aug 08 00:18:19 c6354976113c sensu-client[1534]: /etc/init.d/sensu-service: 
line 71: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory
```

Is that true? In order to check that another debug step was added: `ls /etc/init.d`. [The outcome](https://travis-ci.org/030/ansible-sensu/jobs/150506495) is as follows:

```
$ sudo docker exec --tty "$(cat ${container_id})" env TERM=xterm ls /etc/init.d

README  sensu-api  sensu-client  sensu-server  sensu-service  uchiwa
```

`functions` is indeed missing. [This post](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/339) indicated that `initscripts` needs to be installed. When [this package was added to the Dockerfile](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu/compare/gh49_ci?expand=1#diff-6519f5ad82b19b2dc34dcc3c22e5d863R19) and the build ran again [it succeeded](https://travis-ci.org/030/ansible-sensu/builds/150510557).